# Нужна ли в этом кейсе csrf защита?

Tags: cookie, безопасность, csrf

Если я всегда использую `POST/PUT/DELETE` запросы, то-есть не использую `query` параметры типа `domain.com/path?key=value`, нужна ли мне CSRF защита? Можно же заксекьюрить куки всякими `sameSite`, `HTTPOnly`, `Secure` и прочими полями.

Мой сервер для фронта - это, по сути API. То-есть он не рендерит HTML, не работает с формами. Только `POST/PUT/DELETE` запросы, или `GET` запросы, но без данных в URL.

Проблема в то, что middleware для моего фреймворка (https://docs.gofiber.io/api/middleware/csrf) работает не правильно (или я не понимаю, как должна работать `CSRF` защита). На `GET` запрос он ставит `csrf cookie`, но при повторном запросе он не обновляется - ставиться тот-же. Но да, без этого `cookie` `POST` запросы не проходят, но даже когда я получил этот `cookie` от `GET` запроса, потом успешно отправил `POST` запрос - `csrf cookie` не обновляется.

И тут либо я не правильно понимаю, как работает `CSRF` защита. Она же должны каждый запрос генерить новый `csrf` токен. Либо этот middleware не правильно написан (в принципе можно переписать).

Но, если логика такая, что клиент сначала с помощью `GET` запроса получает этот токен, а потом только может пользоваться `POST/PUT/DELETE` методами, то нужно создать эндпоинт типа `get_csrf`, так как клиент может отправить `POST` первым (ведь я не рендерю HTML). На насколько правильно делать такой эндопоинт? Пока изучал этот вопрос ничего про это не нашел.

Но не совсем понимаю, что мешает злоумышленнику украсть этот CSRF токен, если он уже украл cookie и воспользоваться им (этот токен ведь тоже в cookie лежит)? Или здесь расчет только на лаг во времени, типа злоумышленник не успеет?

Comment: Если вы предполагаете, что sameSite поддерживается абсолютно всеми используемыми у вас браузерами, то не нужна

Comment: «Она же должны каждый запрос генерить новый csrf токен» — не обязательно, зависит от конкретной реализации

Comment: «что мешает злоумышленнику украсть этот CSRF токен» — суть защиты от CSRF не в защите от кражи, а в предотвращении обработки нежелательных запросов, отправленных с чужих сайтов. От кражи же не спасёт уже ничего

Comment: Ну а вообще, если в вашем случае отправить правильно сформированный запрос с чужого сайта в принципе невозможно (сервер принимает только json и не обрабатывает запросы с html-форм, кроссдоменные ajax-запросы запрещены в CORS-правилах, требуется добавлять HTTP-заголовок с access-токеном и так далее), то CSRF-атаки к вам неприменимы и защищаться от них нет смысла